# Should I use Fat burner or do more exercise?

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat, bmi

I am 27 years of age. I am 5.4 feet tall. I am weighing 80kg these days(BMI 29.6). I want to reduce it to 67kg(BMI 25) 
Three months ago, when i started gym i was weighing 84kg. I cut out sugar,bakery items from my diet, no cold drinks, no junk food. With that i was able to reduce my weight to 80kg. 
My diet is same now a days but i am observing that my weight is not reducing now rather it is stable. When i talked to the gym instructor he told me to use fat burner for this purpose. 
**Questions:**
Should I use Fat Burner or do more exercise? Are the fat burners good for body? Do they work? What are the pros and cons fo using fat burner? 
**My workout routine:**
**Monday Chest exercises:**
1.  Barbel Bench Press(12.5 kg+12.5kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
2.  Inclined Barbel Bench Press(12.5 kg+12.5kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
3.  Inclined Barbel Bench Press, Head is lower(15 kg+15kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
4.  Bench Press butterfly(12kg dumbbells each) 3 sets of 12 reps
5.  Pushups
6.  Dumbbell Pull Over(13kg)3 sets of 12 reps

**Tuesday Wings Plus Back exercise:**
1.  Wide-Grip Pulldowns Behind(7 plates not sure about weight)
2.  Closed-Grip Pulldowns front
3.  Seated Cable Row
4.  Standing T-Bar row wide grip(15kg) 3 sets of 15 reps
5.  Standing T-Bar row closed grip (15kg) 3 sets of 15 reps
6.  Single arm dumbbell Row(12Kg) alternating for both arms

**Wednessday Biceps exercises:**
1.  Ez Bar Curl wide grip (5kg+5kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
2.  Ez Bar Curl closed  grip (5kg+5kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
3.  Seated Biceps Curl (6kg ) alternating arms 3 sets of 24 reps(12  for each arm)
4.  Seated Biceps Curl(6kg) simultaneously both arms, 3 sets of 12 reps
5.  Preacher Curl(5kg +5kg) 3 sets of 12 reps
6.  Cable Hammer Curls
7.  Concentration Curls(6kg) 3 sets of 12 reps for each arm

Thursday Legs exercises
Friday and Saturday mix exercises

Comment: Ephedra/caffeine definitely works, but people overdose on them and die (rarely, but it happens). If you want to start popping that it's a good idea to talk to your doctor first and let them know what you're up to so they can keep track of your blood pressure / heart. Keep the dosage low, *lots* of water, and don't workout/run in heat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a question of drugs versus exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've hit a plateau in your weight loss, it does happen. The body seeks homeostasis, so if you don't change anything for a few months, you'll reach a point where your body is "happy" with where it is and you won't progress.

Getting out of a plateau isn't usually too hard (in my experience), you just need to change things up. I would avoid using fat burners, but then that's just my opinion and I have no scientific basis for it.

Instead, I'd say try and change up your training routine, if you normally do weights, throw in some interval training. If you do interval training, throw in some steady state cardio and some weights.

The idea is that your body will adapt to whatever you're asking it to do, and become more efficient at doing that exercise, and as such, you'll burn less calories while doing it. Try doing something that you've never done before (or not very frequently) that your body isn't used to. It'll feel a lot harder than you'd expect, but it'll hopefully help with shedding more pounds.

The alternative is to try and reduce your daily caloric intake a bit more to see if that helps. I've always found the mixing up your exercise routine to be preferable.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is easy to answer, but your problem is a bit more complex. 
Most fat burners are trying to increase your metabolism, either by adding caffeine or some other "secret" ingredient that will increase your metabolism and help you burn more calories. My personal opinion is that these product do little good other than making somebody else than you richer. I don't see that many pro's or cons in fat burners, they just don't really do any good.

Losing 4 kilo's in three months is not that bad for a steady weight loss program. I'm not sure what your exercises are and what your normal diet is. Let me give you some guidelines that have worked for me. I lost 7.7 kilo's in 5 months and I am still losing weight.

First look at your exercise level and the exercises you are doing. I do a lot of muscle training. Not really to bulk, but muscles are "expensive" tissue and will increase your metabolism (amount of calories you burn) considerably. You don't have to look like a body builder, but the more muscles you build, the higher your metabolism and thus the more calories your burn per day. If you do train your muscles, do train all muscle groups equally to ensure your body develops normally.

Next to your muscle training add in some fat burning training, like biking or running. This will help you burn your visceral fat, which resides around your organs and is the unhealthy part of your fat. Biking can also be riding to work if it is a considerable distance (>10 km).

Now your diet. If you mainly train your muscles, you will need more carbs than fat. Fat is not readily available and muscle training is explosive, so you need to get the ATP in your tissue. Fat food will not provide you this energy and you are going to need the energy for the muscle training. Went eating, try to eat 6 times a day small portions. This will help you increase your metabolism and it will keep your stomach smaller, which prevents you from feeling hungry all the time. Also look for the kind of carbs you're eating. Don't eat too many "fast carbs", since they will be turned into fat reserves that will be difficult to get rid of. Slow carbs take more time to digest and it will provide you the supply of energy over the day.

Do take in mind that now and again you will reach a plateau where your weight will stay the same for a short while and then will start dropping. This is normal, your weight will not drop in a steady line.

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: Just read it. Interestingly, you have a larger number of exercises, but do less series than I do. I don't think it really matters, since your training the same muscle group on a single day. I'm missing the stamina work outs. and take an extra day of rest or one day of lower exercise.

Answer (score -1):

I am against supplements. I do take one for a proven deficiency: magnesium, but even that I try to compensate and eat as much as I can in my diet (mainly cruciferous vegetables and nuts). I am not a conservative person when it comes to nutrition, on the contrary, but after multi year studies, most of the supplements either provide no long term benefits, or come with serious health dangers such as heavy metals.
Your goal is not to lose weight. Repeat it after me: Your goal is not to lose weight. Your goal is to lose body fat.
Your trainer seems like he is trying to give you the easy way out. I am a trainer, and I am appalled by what he suggested.
But first things first: You have to tell us about your workout regime.
All things worth fighting for are hard. ALL. You want to lose fat, and get toned fast?
Then these must be your guidelines:

1)Do a 20-45 minute rigorous cardio every day. HIIT or even better SMIT. SMIT, as I've seen is even better at preserving muscles, and the studies back me up.
You want it get done, the easy way? Go on a treadmill and walk at a pace of 3.5mph for 1 minute, then for the next minute run for 7-10 mph, depending on what you CAN do. Walk again for 1.5-2 minutes, and run again. Change your speed accordingly, to max speed you can do, or to maybe a 85-90% run.

2)Do proper weight lifting 3 times a week. Most women I know go to the machines. Machines are fine for acquiring muscle memory, but for anything else they are useless. So, three times a week do squats, overhead presses and bench presses. In every single workout. Do a max of 4 sets of 12 repetitions. 10 is even better in my opinion. Choose appropriate weight, NO YOU WON'T GET BULKY, it's the growth hormone that men have that makes us bulky, not simply choosing to lift heavier. The appropriate weight is the one you can't lift in your final repetition. For the rest of your weight lifting days, do lunges, hip thrusts and calf raises for your legs, dumbbell flys, and incline bench press for your chest, lateral raises for your shoulders, curls for biceps and overhead extensions for triceps, and the only muscles I allow you to use machines, as you probably can't do pull ups, is lat pulldowns and seated rows for your back muscles. Do your weightlifting sessions for about an hour, before you do cardio for 20 minutes.

3)Eat whole food protein, as much as you can. 110 grams a day, seems appropriate for your lean body weight. 1 whole chicken breast and a Greek yogurt a day, or 4 eggs (eat the yoke in two of them), half a pound of turkey and a quarter pound of very low fat cheese. Make this your mantra, no matter what, your protein goals WILL BE MET. Your destroyed muscles after a workout, seek protein to replenish and become stronger to adapt to the challenges you are giving them. Muscle mass also has a higher metabolic need for calories, so that's another plus. They also need something else:

4)Carbs. Good, complex carbs which will give you energy for a great part of the day, and you won't get hungry soon. Leafy vegetables, lentils, bananas, brown rice and oats are great choices.

In conclusion, tire yourself out. If you are not super tired in your weightlifting days, then you are doing something wrong. Also, try to eat complex carbs, as they dietary fiber will keep the hunger pangs at the bay.
Good luck, and NEVER give up.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: (1) Only elite athletes should consider training more than 6 days a week, it's just not effective. (2) Machines are great for lots of things you have not mentioned, where the hell are your rowing movements in your recommendation? You shouldn't train to failure every session either. (3) That amount of protein is overkill, dietary cholesterol is not worth worrying about (wrt. egg yolks). Tiredness/soreness is a bad indicator of how successful/well a program is going. Any idiot can tire someone out, but it takes a professional to train them effectively.

Comment: First of all there are row movements in my recommendation. So, READ again.
Secondly, weightlifting every day is ineffective, light cardio, it's not.
You SHOULD train every session to failure, that's your safest way to hypertrophy. Period.
Then, this amount of protein is recommended by every single health organisation, including WHO, as the maximum amount of protein intake in order to achieve protein synthesis. I hace a freaking MSc in Sports nutrition.
Finally, tiredness is a good measure of how much your muscles worked during a workout,a lack of it is the best indicator of a BAD workout.